# Folder exists in container but cannot cd into the folder in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

I have a multistage build docker file, I'm having a problem with my dockerfile. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong so any help would be appreciated.
A little description of my folder structure for which i'm writing the dockerfile. I have a website that calls to a python script which does image segmentation. The idea is to create a multistage dockerfile that installs my node dependencies and start the server and then to install all my python dependencies as well so that I can run a docker-compose file with both my front-end and back-end. With that being said, here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as build

WORKDIR '/app/Neos-Application/backend'




COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install 

COPY . .


FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04 

ENV NODE_VERSION=12.6.0
ENV TZ=Asia/Calcutta
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone


COPY --from=build /app/Neos-Application/backend /app/Neos-Application/backend

RUN apt update && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential gcc software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y python3.8 python3-distutils  python3-pip && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2 && \
    apt clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

WORKDIR '/app/Neos-Application/backend'

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN cd ./COVAIv2/MIScnn && pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
RUN python3.8 setup.py install


CMD ["npm","start"]
```

ls -l gives this output:

```
 => ERROR [stage-1 8/9] RUN ls -l && cd ./COVAIv2/MIScnn && pip3 install -r requirements.txt            0.1s
------
 > [stage-1 8/9] RUN ls -l && cd ./COVAIv2/MIScnn && pip3 install -r requirements.txt:
#20 0.126 total 164
#20 0.126 drwxr-xr-x   8 root root   4096 Sep 12 15:13 COVAIv2 
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root   2305 Sep 12 15:20 Dockerfile.dev
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root   1073 Jun 23 01:13 LICENSE
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Jun 23 01:13 README.md
#20 0.126 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Sep 12 15:13 controllers
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root   1140 Jun 23 01:13 index.js
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root   3243 Jun 23 01:13 jwtRS256.key
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root    775 Jun 23 01:13 jwtRS256.key.pub
#20 0.126 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 12 15:13 models
#20 0.126 drwxr-xr-x 321 root root  12288 Sep 12 15:14 node_modules
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root 105415 Jul 15 10:49 package-lock.json
#20 0.126 -rw-r--r--   1 root root    833 Aug 18 02:47 package.json
#20 0.126 drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Sep 12 15:14 routes
#20 0.126 drwxr-xr-x   7 root root   4096 Sep 12 15:14 uploads
#20 0.126 /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ./COVAIv2/MIScnn
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ls -l && cd ./COVAIv2/MIScnn && pip3 install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 2
```

The error says that I can't cd into the ./COVAIv2.

Comment: Search your Dockerfile, no `ls -l` defined, how you get the output of `ls -l`, where you define it, you need post the dockerfile exactly you use which helps to find the root cause of your issue.

Comment: @atline I have updated the output of the command and the entire dockerfile is written here. Can you be more specific as to what you need more?

Comment: Maybe you need add `ls ./COVAIv2/MIScnn` to see if `MIScnn` there? The error maybe not caused by `CoVAiv2` but by no subfolder `MIScnn`

Comment: `=> ERROR [stage-1 8/9] RUN ls ./COVAIv2 && pip3 install -r requirements.txt                            0.2s
------
 > [stage-1 8/9] RUN ls ./COVAIv2 && pip3 install -r requirements.txt:
#20 0.239 ls: cannot access './COVAIv2': No such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ls ./COVAIv2 && pip3 install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 2`

Comment: Extremely strange beyond my knowledge ...... You can do `apt install` here so you are surely `root`, so no idea what happened... Wait other folks...

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `COPY --from=build /app/Neos-Application/backend /app/Neos-Application/backend` before creating `/app/Neos-Application`. Change to `COPY --from=build /app/ /app/` or run `mkdir /app/ && mkdir /app/Neos-Application/` prior.

Comment: I tried doing this. I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my folder name to covaiv2 and its working now . I guess capital folder names aren't treated well in dockerfile? Not too sure .